# Kafka-Streams throwing NullPointerException when consuming

Tags: groovy, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-streams

I have this problem:

When I'm consuming from a topic using the Processor API, when inside the processor the method `context().forward(K, V)`, Kafka Streams throws a null pointer exception.

This is the stacktrace of it:

```
Exception in thread "StreamThread-1" java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.forward(StreamTask.java:336)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:187)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.ProcessorContext$forward.call(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
at com.bnsf.ltf.processor.ConversionProcessor.process(ConversionProcessor.groovy:23)
at com.bnsf.ltf.processor.ConversionProcessor.process(ConversionProcessor.groovy)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.process(ProcessorNode.java:68)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.forward(StreamTask.java:338)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:187)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.SourceNode.process(SourceNode.java:64)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.process(StreamTask.java:174)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runLoop(StreamThread.java:320)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.run(StreamThread.java:218)
```

My Gradle dependencies look like this:

```
compile('org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all')
compile('org.apache.kafka:kafka-streams:0.10.0.0')
```

Update: I tried with version 0.10.0.1 and it still throws the same error.

This is the code of the Topology I'm building...

```
 topologyBuilder.addSource('inboundTopic', stringDeserializer, stringDeserializer, conversionConfiguration.inTopic)
    .addProcessor('conversionProcess', new ProcessorSupplier() {
        @Override
        Processor get() {
            return conversionProcessor
        }
    }, 'inboundTopic')
    .addSink('outputTopic', conversionConfiguration.outTopic, stringSerializer, stringSerializer, 'conversionProcess')

    stream = new KafkaStreams(topologyBuilder, streamConfig)
    stream.start()
```

My processor looks like this:

```
@Override
void process(String key, String message) {
    // Call to a service and the return of the service is set on the
    // converted local variable named converted
    context().forward(key, converted)
    context().commit()
}
```

Comment: Not sure. According to the code https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/0.10.0.0/streams/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/streams/processor/internals/StreamTask.java#L336 I assume `thisNode` is null what would be a bug -- maybe try to use `0.10.0.1` which might contain a fix for it -- of even better, upgrade to `0.10.1.1` (or `0.10.2.0` that will be released the next weeks)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provide your Processor directly.

```
.addProcessor('conversionProcess', () -> new MyProcessor(), 'inboundTopic')
```

`MyProcessor` should, in turn, inherit from `AbstractProcessor`.